# Add class based on some condition Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am working with ng2 project and I need a help with one task, where should I add css class, only for one item from array.

I got sommething like this:

```
<div class="ds-photo__item" *ngFor="let albumPhoto of albumPhotos">
  <div class="ds-photo__item--cover">
    <img class="ds-photo__item--cover-photo" [src]="albumPhoto.url" alt="" (click)="choseCover(albumPhoto)" [class.selected]="...">
  </div>
</div>
```

And I need add class select only for one item which is choosen by function below:

```
selectCover() {
    if (this.album.cover) {
        this.cover = this.albumPhotos.find( photo => photo.id === this.album.cover );
        console.log("COVER: ", this.cover);
        this.isCover = true;
    } else { this.isCover = false }
}
```

after that, I have one object with current cover of album. I need to add class "selected" to listed item, whuch is actualy cover.

I need something like this: 
[class.selected]="if albumPhoto.id === cover.id"

or sommething similar. There is possible to pass function, not only variable in `[class.my-class]`?

Please for hints!
Regards Greg

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ngClass](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#ngClass) as follows :

```
<img class="ds-photo__item--cover-photo" [src]="albumPhoto.url" alt="" (click)="choseCover(albumPhoto)" [ngClass]="{selected : albumPhoto.id === cover.id}">
```

Answer (score 0):

Done with:

```
[class.selected]="cover.id === albumPhoto.id"
```

I hope it will help someone.

Bye!

Answer (score 0):

If you need only one class to be applied based on some condition then use
`[class.selected]="cover.id === albumPhoto.id"`

```
<img class="ds-photo__item--cover-photo" [src]="albumPhoto.url" alt="" (click)="choseCover(albumPhoto)" [class.selected]="cover.id === albumPhoto.id">
[class.selected]="cover.id === albumPhoto.id"
```

but If you have multiple class to be applied based on some condition then just use this format

`[ngClass]="{selected : albumPhoto.id === cover.id}"`

```
<img class="ds-photo__item--cover-photo" [src]="albumPhoto.url" alt="" (click)="choseCover(albumPhoto)" [ngClass]="{selected : albumPhoto.id === cover.id}">
```